# Returning boolean function with another function

Tags: java, function, boolean

I am wondering how to do this.

I have a function, let's say

```
public boolean function() {
// many if statements here
// functionReturn(); after each statement
}

public void functionReturn() {
if(isMade) {
  return true; (for function) I need this to return the FUNCTION() true
    }
return false; (for function) I need this to return the FUNCTION() false
}
```

Basically, my function() boolean function has to be returned by another function, due to lots of code inside of function() - I don't want to repeat the code all over again, that's why I'd like to use returnRawr() to make it clearer and just better.

isMade is a public boolean variable.

Any tips are more than welcome, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: It would help if you would show a sample of `function`. In particular, are you only wanting to return in *some* cases? Your question is very unclear at the moment. A complete example - even if it's only fairly simple - would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A method can't return anything with `void` as return type.

Do it carefully otherwise it will result in an `StackOverflowError` as shown in below sample code.

```
public boolean function() {       
   return functionReturn(); 
}

public boolean functionReturn() {
   return function();
}
```

Comment: How can I do this then?

Comment: Yes, but if I do this, it will return functionReturn() false or true, I need functionReturn to return the "main" Function() true or false

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```
public boolean function() {
   //many if statements here
   return functionReturn();
}

public boolean functionReturn() { 
    return isMade;
}
```

The gist of it is you're returning the value returned by functionReturn(). functionReturn() returns the value of isMade.

But your question is pretty unclear. I feel like this isn't what you're looking for, since you could probably just return `isMade` inside `function()`.